# Hí Cicerónem ipsum sécum iúnxérunt, nam eum semper díléxerant

Tags: translation-check, translation-explanation, wheelocks-latin

In the 9. practice and review exercise of the page 86 of Wheelock's Latin steht:

> Hí Cicerónem ipsum sécum iúnxérunt, nam eum semper díléxerant

My attempt to translation is the following:

> These of Cicero had joined themselves with Cicero himself, because they had always appreciated him.

And my original native speaker Spanish translation:

> Estos de Cicero han juntado al mismísimo Cicero con ellos, porque siempre lo han apreciado.

I am not sure about the use of *ipsum sécum*

---

#### Edited note:

After the response of Sebastian Koppehel, implied that *Cicerónem* is not a genitive I think I realized my mistake and therefore my attempt to translate it again goes like

> Estos se han juntado con el mismísimo Cicero, porque siempre lo han apreciado.

Translating it back to English

> These had joined themselves to Cicero himself, because they had always appreciated him.

---

I would prefer a explanation in Spanish.

Comment: Note that "stehet" for "steht" is technically not wrong, only poetic ;-) But are you learning German and Latin in parallel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your translation seems fine to me except:

- "these of Cicero" makes no sense and is not found in the Latin -- *hi* is just "these" (people, men, senators, etc.).
- you got the tense of *iunxerunt* wrong, it is just perfect, so it should be "these joined."
- Technically, *Ciceronem ipsum* (Cicero himself) is the object of *iungere*, and *secum* refers to the subjects, so strictly speaking, it should be: "these joined Cicero himself to themselves."

Note that *ipsum* often simply has an emphasizing or intensifying force, and this appears to be the case here, so you could for example translate it as "even Cicero" if it seems appropriate in context. "Join" for *iungere* also does not always work best in English, sometimes "attach" or something similar is preferable.

Put together, a possible translation would be: "These men attached even Cicero himself to their faction, because they had always appreciated him."

Comment: I don't think that I get the tense of *iunxerunt* wrong, but I get the tense of *had joined* wrong. Check my original attempt in Spanish. That aside what is not *Cireronem* an genitive?

Comment: @Dolphínus *Ciceronem* is accusative: *Ciceronis* is genitive. Concerning your translation, "han juntado" is equivalent to English "*have* (not *had*) joined." You should have "habían apreciado" (="had appreciated") for the pluperfect.

Comment: *dilexerunt* = "han apreciado"; *dilexerant* = "habían apreciado"

Comment: @brianpck Can made it in an answer?

Comment: @brianpck also, I am sure that a verbatim translation of *dilexerant* would make it an Spanish sentence with a clear meaning that they stopped to appreciate Cicero in the past.